# Google Sheets API Post 404 error

Tags: ios, google-api, google-api-client, google-sheets-api

Am trying to post data to google spread sheet but am getting 404 error,verified my sheet id and all everything looks fine but still am getting a 404 error, below is my code

```
NSString *baseUrl = @"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/";
NSString *spreadsheetId = @"MYKEY/edit";
NSString *range = @"Sheet1!A2:E";

baseUrl= [baseUrl stringByAppendingString:spreadsheetId];
baseUrl = [baseUrl stringByAppendingString:@"/values/"];
baseUrl = [baseUrl stringByAppendingString:range];


NSMutableDictionary * params=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"RAW",@"valueInputOption", nil];

NSURL *postURL=[GTLUtilities URLWithString:baseUrl queryParameters:params];

NSLog(@"base url is %@", postURL);


GTLObject * body=[[GTLObject alloc]init];


NSMutableArray * contentArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray * titleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Student Name",@"Gender",@"Class Level",@"Home State",@"Major",@"Extracurricular Activity",nil];
NSMutableArray * wheelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TEST",@"TEST",@"50.00",@"100.00",@"2",@"2", nil];

[contentArray addObjectsFromArray:titleArray];
[contentArray addObjectsFromArray:wheelArray];

NSLog(@"content array is %@", contentArray);


NSMutableDictionary * bodyDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:range,@"range",@"ROWS",@"majorDimension",@"HELLO",@"values", nil];
NSLog(@"body dict %@",bodyDict);


body.JSON=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"range",range,@"majorDimension",@"ROWS",@"values",@"HELLO", nil];


[self.service fetchObjectByUpdatingObject:body forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl] completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {

    if (error==nil) {

        NSLog(@"posted content successfully");
    }
}];
```

Comment: It looks like your token has been revoked. Try reauthorize your account :)

Comment: I just did reset my simulator and done authorization again,same issue exists.

Comment: Can you post the detail of error?

Comment: <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v4/spreadsheets/1tJd4toWFxmHAEOeONauRPcuH_rWJOESLQT7TvCIK0x0/edit/values/Sheet1!A2:E</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Comment: remove **edit** and try again :)

Comment: <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v4/spreadsheets/1tJd4toWFxmHAEOeONauRPcuH_rWJOESLQT7TvCIK0x0/values/Sheet1!A2:E</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete **/edit** in you **spreadsheetId**

Add a number after **E** column in your **range**

Comment: I just did that but still am facing same issue <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v4/spreadsheets/1tJd4toWFxmHAEOeONauRPcuH_rWJOESLQT7TvCIK0x0/values/Sheet1!A2:E</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
}

Comment: Now am getting 403 error  Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "(Request had insufficient authentication scopes.)" UserInfo={error=Request had insufficient authentication scopes., NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Request had insufficient authentication scopes.), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7fdf43e417d0: {code:403 message:"Request had insufficient authentication scopes." errors?:[1] status?:"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}

Comment: Add a number after **E** column in your **range**

Comment: Make sure that your **scope** is **https:// www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets**  (remove the space)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your followup comments, after fixing the issues others pointed out you're now failing with insufficient scopes.  In order to tell the server the user granted your app permission, you need to request OAuth authorization on behalf of the user. The [iOS QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios) explains how to do this, by creating an auth controller:

`// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Sheets API.
    - (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthController {
      GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
      // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
      // resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
      NSArray *scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", nil];
      authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
               initWithScope:[scopes componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
                    clientID:kClientID
                clientSecret:nil
            keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                    delegate:self
            finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
      return authController;
    }`

(The quickstart uses the `spreadsheets.readonly` scope, but I changed it to `spreadsheets` in the above because it looks like you want to modify data.)

You'll need to make sure the createAuthController method is called correctly (and only when necessary), and that things flow properly when it finishes authorizing too.  The quickstart guide explains that in detail.